# Inductive reasoning and probability: probability of the conclusion itself or probability of the supporting relation?

Tags: logic

It is often admitted that inductive reasoning has something to do with probability.

While in a ( valid) deduction the premises necessarily imply the conclusion, in an inductive reasoning the premises make the conclusion probable.

But this is somewhat ambiguous: does probability qualify here the conclusion itself or the supporting relation between the premisses and the conclusion?

Suppose P1, P2, P3 are the premises of an inductive reasoning and C is the conclusion.

What does it mean to say that this inductive reasoning is strong.

Does it mean that

(1) Probabably ( P1&P2&P3 --> C) is true.

or that

(2) P1&P2&P3 --> (Probably C is true)?

It seems difficult  to admit interpretation (2) for inserting the probability notion in the conclusion itself might turn the reasoning into a deductive one.

(1) No woman has ever been elected President of the US. 
(2) Therefore, probably the next President will not be a woman.

This argument is not inductive ( it seems to me) since the ( statistical) probability of the gender of the next President is defined by the actual gender of the previous presidents. So, arguably, this reasoning is deductive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (2) P1&P2&P3 --> (Probably C is true)?
>
> It seems difficult  to admit interpretation (2) for inserting the probability notion in the conclusion itself might turn the reasoning into a deductive one.

I see your concern. Maybe one solution is to associate the 'probably' with the inference itself, i.e.

$P1,P2,P3 \overset{Probably}{-->} C$

But I think the best thing to do is to just stick with:

$P1,P2,P3 --> C$

And say that this is a strong inductive inference (rather than a deductive one), in that if $P1,P2,P3$ are true, then $C$ is probably (rather than definitely) true.